# The same CheckBox but it has different display in two different Android machine?

Tags: android, android-widget

I want to customize my CheckBox on my Android mechine, but it has different display in different android mechine?

Here is in my Milestone 2 (Android 2.2):
[image]

And in my Sony Ericsson LT18i (Android 2.3.4):
[image]

And shop_near_choise_bg.9.png:
[image]

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/shop_near_distance_selector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.0"
        android:background="@drawable/shop_near_choise_bg"
        android:button="@null"
        android:padding="0dip"
        android:text="@string/shop_near" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can see you don't have place for content in you drawable(black px right and bottom of picture). Specify this area and check it again.

If you use draw9patch there you can see area for content.